# Slack default channel notifications

Tags: slack

Is it possible to create a channel in Slack and set the default notification preferences for (other) new users joining the channel?

I need this in order to automatically join to certain channels users with relatively low technical skills, but to have the notifications automatically muted for that channel so that it doesn't annoy them too much.

Comment: I don't believe the accepted answer actually answers the question, and I'm looking for an answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this:
`https://{your_slack_team}.slack.com/account/notifications#channel_specific_settings`

Comment: On my org's free slack plan this just brings me to a page where I can configure notification settings for myself, but not for any specific channels.