# Free Slack plan - how to configure default notifications for new users?

Tags: slack

Does anyone know how to configure default notification settings for all new users who join a Slack workspace?

I've gotten feedback that new users are getting overwhelmed and many of them just stop using Slack instead of trying to change their notification settings.

I found the following answer but it does not address the problem: [Slack default channel notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167761/slack-default-channel-notifications)